# “Meet” of Zorn’s Lemma and Law of Excluded Middle

Tags: logic, set-theory, axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

Work in intuitionistic logic (IL), and assume ZF.

The Axiom of Choice (AC) implies both Zorn’s Lemma (ZL) and the law of excluded middle (EM). Furthermore, AC is the “join” of ZL and EM, since we can prove AC if we assume both of these principles.

The “meet” of ZL and EM is **the set of formulas that are both provable from ZL (alone) and provable from EM (alone)**. What do we know about this meet? For example, is it equivalent to a single proposition in the language of set theory?

Comment: It's equivalent to the single statement $\mathbf{ZL}\lor\mathbf{EM}$. But it would be nice to have an example for which the equivalence involves some genuine information.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I was hoping that this idea of "involving some genuine information" might be captured by being equivalent to a single proposition in the language of set theory $\mathcal{L} = \{ \in \}$. (Since $\mathbf{ZL} \vee \mathbf{EM}$ is a proper axiom schema.) But perhaps this is too much to ask for. I would also be interested to know if $\mathbf{ZL} \vee \mathbf{EM}$ is non-obviously equivalent to some other axiom schema.

Comment: "Provable from (ZL or EM)" is equivalent to "provable from ZL **and** provable from EM", not "provable from ZL **or** provable from EM". Which do you mean? (And why?)

Comment: @Karl Good catch, thanks! I meant the former, because the latter is equivalent to full ZFC (i.e. ZF + AC).

Comment: Hmm, I don't think the latter is equivalent to "provable from (ZL and EM)", because proofs using both principles are not allowed.

Comment: @Karl Ah yes, another good catch. I slipped up because the latter set of sentences is not closed under logical implication, and I naively assumed that it would be. The closure of the latter set of sentences under logical implication is full ZFC.

Comment: @GavinDooley Over IZF, excluded middle is equivalent to a single instance of it, $\forall a \forall b (a \in b \lor a \notin b)$ (even over a weak theory, this is equivalent to LEM for all $\Delta_0$ formulas). If you weaken the constructive theory, then the axiom of choice doesn’t imply full excluded middle, only $\Delta_0$ LEM.

Comment: Consequences are studied in "Bell (1997) Zorn’s lemma and complete Boolean algebras in intuitionistic type", or more recently "Wessel (2017) Choice, extension, conservation" 
Btw. you can't just say "assume ZF", due to the $\exists$ in the Regularity axiom, which basically acts as a choice principle. Not giving generic choices $x\in X\in D$ in a domain $D$, but extremal $x\in X\in V$ in the universe $V$. You use Set Induction over Regularity, just like you use $\omega$-induction over well-orderedness. Think $( \forall(x\in X). P(x) )\to Q$ tame vs. $(\exists(x\in X). \neg P(x))\lor Q$ spooky.

Comment: Morning. Just looked around and in topos theory they still publish papers on where ZL and lattice results hold and fail. ZL holds often but there's exceptions also, see e.g. papers linked in an nCafe post. Now my impression is that it's the jump from ZL to AC which makes AC affect the logic. You look at chains of partial funcs that cover more and more elements of the dom $D$. ZL gives you a max $f$ with $f\le g\to f=g$. To get to $\forall X\in D.X\in dom(f)$ you want $\forall X\in D.\exists g. (X\in dom(g)\land f\le g)$. But one-point extension may not be possible for non-detachable $dom(f)$.